# Tax rebate on home loan

Tags: income-tax, mortgage, tax-deduction, india

I am govt. employee & got a home loan from SBI  to construct new building on my mother's property and map also passed in name of my mother . I am borrower and she is co-borrower on the the loan. Can I use EMI paid for my tax saving.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the Land is in your mother's name and you are building a house on it. Is the house on your name or on your Mother's name.

For self constructed property, to be eligible for tax rebate on the EMI, the house has to be in your name. As you Mother is co-borrower, you are entitled to only 50% rebate unless your mother signs to release her 50% rebate to you.